# Is it safe to use the css property "visibility"?

Tags: css, visibility

Is it safe to use the css property "visibility"? Will it work in all major browsers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_class_visibility.asp) it's supported in all major browsers.

Please consider if you are actually looking to use `visibility` as the element will still take up space on the page (it will just appear blank). If you want it to be as if the element isn't on the page at all then consider using `display:none` instead.

Comment: I know this post is from 2011 but I would definitely not consider it being an "issue" it's more of a feature to me. Else there would be no difference with `display:none;`

Comment: I'd agree with you - I'll update the wording. This has been a problem for me in the past (well, working with people who considered them equal and misused them) so I guess that's why I said issue :)

Answer (score 5):

according to http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_visibility.asp yes:

> The visibility property is supported in all major browsers.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility), it has the following browser support:

```
╔════════════════╦═════════════╗═══════════════════╗══════════╗════════════╗
║     Chrome     ║   Firefox   ║ Internet Explorer ║  Opera   ║   Safari   ║ 
╠════════════════╬═════════════╣═══════════════════╣══════════╣════════════╣
║       1.0      ║     1.0     ║       4.0         ║    4.0   ║     1.0    ║
║                ║             ║                   ║          ║            ║
╚════════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```

With the following exceptions (for tables):

> Support for *visibility: collapse* on table elements varies. Chrome and
>   Safari treat collapse like hidden, leaving a white gap; they support
>   it only on `<tr>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, and `<tfoot>`, but not on `<col>` and
>   `<colgroup>` elements. Firefox doesn’t hide borders when hiding `<col>`
>   and `<colgroup>` elements if *border-collapse: collapse* is set. In Opera,
>   it works on table elements, but doesn’t seem to hide a `<tfoot>` if it
>   is adjacent to a visible `<tbody>`.

Answer (score 3):

The visibility property is supported in all major browsers.

Note: No versions of Internet Explorer (including IE8) support the property values "inherit" or "collapse".

Answer (score 1):

`visibility` works well, but `opacity` needs some workarounds. Notably, IE8 and below (not sure about IE9) don't support it, but they do support a `filter` that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be fine:

http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_class_visibility.asp